# A multi-layer point displacement option to prevent overlapping across layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology

I am in the process of trying to create a webmap using Qgis2Web. For those who aren't familiar - a toggleable legend requires a unique layer rather than a categorized symbology/rule based labelling.

However, when it is kept in one layer I can use the above alongside the point displacement render such that there will be no overlapping points but then the QGIS web legend is no longer toggleable so I have to choose between overlapping points or a non-toggleable legend.

Is there a way to displace points across layers, similar to the now deprecated refFunctions plugin, for more than 2 layers?

Below is what I'm angling for on the left and then the two right images are the overlapping in the same spot that I would rather both push left and right. I can't unfortunately just offset left and right because there are a lot of different combinations of layers.

[image: Desired output]
[image: Output as current]
[image: Overlapping]